# Are there any linear algebra books in which matroid theory is described and used?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, matroids

I am interested in matroid theory now.

Are there any linear algebra books in which matroid theory is described and used?

Comment: For applications to CS you might have more luck with a combinatorial optimization book

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thank you very much for the information. I will search combinatorial optimization books.

Answer (score 2):

Oxley's Matroid Theory (google books preview here: https://books.google.com.mt/books?id=puKta1Hdz-8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false ) is a pretty good book for this.  I think you're more likely to find references to matroid theory in (algebraic) graph theory books than linear algebra ones though.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your information, postmortes. Oxley's book is difficult for me.

Comment: I am interested in how matroid theory is used in linear algebra or computer science, but I am not so interested in matroid theory itself.

Comment: @tchappyha I think directly going for applications may be difficult. It is easy to learn from the perspective that you need very little other math background but hard from an applied perspective because it is taught as a pure math subject. So you will get all the formalisms, exact definitions and rigorous proofs. A number of basic facts about linear algebra can also be phrased in matroid theory but this primarly useful to understand matroid theory if you already know linear algebra, not the other way round.

Comment: @quarague Thank you very much for your advice. I wanna read matroid theory book, but I have many subjects I must learn, for example, multivariable calculus, abstract algebra, linear algebra. I guess matroid theory is not as important as calculus, abstract algebra, linear algebra. But I will try to learn matroid if possible.

Comment: Does anyone know some aplication of matroid theory on highschool contest problems?